# How to press enter in JTable cell programmatically?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I created a `JTable`, I want when user press an OK button and cursor in last cell, cursor moves to next row. I tried this but did not work:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();   

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Enter);   
robot.keyRelease(keyEvent.Vk_Enter);
```

Comment: You're going to have to do some work, but as a starting point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666489/shifting-the-focus-from-one-cell-to-another-in-jtable-on-tab-press/11667282#11667282

Comment: thanks 
@MadProgrammer